# Django Form Upload Success Message

Tags: django, file-upload

I have a dashboard where it lets you upload files and displays the files you uploaded.  It redirects you back to the dashboard when you submit the upload.  The problem is I want to display a success message saying your file was uploaded, but I cannot figure out how to achieve this as I'm just redirecting them to the same page.  Here is the view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/dashboard-login/')
def dashboard(request):
    current_user = request.user
    current_client = request.user.client

    files = ClientUploads.objects.filter(client=current_client)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = ClientUploads(client=current_client, file_upload = request.FILES['file_upload'])
            new_file.save()

        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    data = {'form': form, 'client': current_client, 'files': files}
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And I know render_to_response is deprecated I will switch that out soon.  But how can I display a success message?  I'm not sure how to submit this with AJAX so I don't know how to display a message since it refreshes the page after you submit the file.

Any solutins or suggestions you could provide would help a ton.  A small example would go a long way towards helping me solve this.

I would also like to include a progress bar, which from my research  would require a custom upload handlers with a progress bar.  Would I be able to display the success message and add the progress bar in this same way?  If so could anyone provide an example of this?

Thanks for any input, I've been stuck here for a good bit now.

Comment: I have never used it myself, so I won't put this into an answer, but I think you can make use of the [Message Framework of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/).

Comment: Will check it out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `views.py` under `if request.method ==POST` you can add `messages.success(request, 'File upload successful')` so it would look something like:

```
def dashboard(request):
    current_user = request.user
    current_client = request.user.client

    files = ClientUploads.objects.filter(client=current_client)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = ClientUploads(client=current_client, file_upload = req uest.FILES['file_upload'])
            new_file.save()
            messages.success(request, 'File upload successful')
```

Then, in your template:

```
  <ul class="messages">
      {% for message in messages %}
      <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

That should do what you want!